# fql query problem in php

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I want to fetch the names of users on facebook. For that, I tried using FQL query. The code is,

```
$result = $facebook->api_client->fql_query("SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid='$user_id');
```

But there is some problem with this. I guess the query is not getting executed or it is returning null values. I also tried using users.getInfo as follows,

```
$result = $facebook->api_client->users_getInfo($user_id,'name');
```

But again, the same problem.

I tried to display the array as,

```
echo $result['name];
```

So, I tried both the codes as,

```
if(!$facebook->api_client->fql_query("SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid='$user_id')) {
   echo "Error.";
}
```

I have included both facebook.php and facebookapi_php5_restlib.php in my php file. Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

now i can fixed this problem..
open and modify file facebookapi_php5_restlib.php and like this

```
  public function post_request($method, $params, $server_addr) {
    list($get, $post) = $this->finalize_params($method, $params);
    $post_string = $this->create_url_string($post);
    $get_string = $this->create_url_string($get);
    $url_with_get = $server_addr . '?' . $get_string;
    if ($this->use_curl_if_available && function_exists('curl_init')) 
    {
      $useragent = 'Facebook API PHP5 Client 1.1 (curl) ' . phpversion();
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_with_get);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3600);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3600);
      $result = $this->curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
    } else {

    $content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      $content = $post_string;
      $result = $this->run_http_post_transaction($content_type,$content, $url_with_get);
    }
    return $result;
  }
```

change time out for